# RAID 10 Failed after BIOS flub. Any chance at recovery?

Tags: windows-10, bios, raid, data-recovery, windows-10-v21h2

System Specs (about 11/12 years old):

- Asus Maximus IV Extreme-Z
- i7-2600K
- 32MB DDR3
- Windows 10 Pro - 21H2
- Samsung 980 Pro 1TB (OS)
- Toshiba 7200RPM 5TB (Movies, Music & other media)
- 4x Seagate 3TB in RAID10; Effectively 6TB mirrored (Games, Pictures,
  video projects; generally more crucial non-expendable stuff)

*TLDR: Any way to recover my RAID10 without complete data loss? Read on for specifics*

**Background**: Some time ago I tried to enable an XMP profile in my BIOS. Something didn't jive, so every time my computer restarted I would have to hard boot it and I'd receive a message that "Overclock failed" and it would boot fine into windows. No other problems, except any time I'd have to restart (thank Windows updates).

I finally decided to try and fix whatever the issue was. After hours of messing around (nothing wrong with the computer yet, just no fix for the "OC" issue) I reset the BIOS to default and restarted. Finally booted into Windows, but my RAID was missing. "Crap, I forgot to reset the SATA configuration from AHCI to RAID". Went back into the BIOS, reset SATA controller to RAID.

[POST is once again showing the RAID, but now it's failed.](https://bashify.io/images/JOtUe8) However it's still showing two sequential member disks. Two that should be one of the RAID0. Continue to boot to Windows... but surprisingly there is no recognized OS anymore, /facepalm.

Long story short there, couldn't fix the GPT after several hours trying so reinstalled Windows 10. Back in windows, install IntelRST; [still showing failed RAID but with 2 striped member disks](https://bashify.io/images/8f9Jqf) and two 0kb unknown hard disks and the two disks that should be in the array.

**Problem:**  I would think that if 2 disks of a mirror go out (especially since it's not one of each stripe) then it should be possible to rebuild, but I don't get an option to rebuild in the RST GUI. I can Delete the current array or mark the disks that should be in the array as spares, but that's it.

So, any hope here? What are my options? If I delete the array and re-create it exactly as it is (same disks, same name etc.) would that restore it? If I go that route as a hail-mary, is it better to do it with the RST Windows GUI or in the boot-up controller settings?

Thanks in advance for any advice and assistance.

*FWIW: I have 3-2-1 backups of the essential/non-expendable stuff... but I'd really love to not have to reinstall all the expendable stuff or spend the hours downloading my TB's of backups if I can avoid it.*

Comment: What are you asking, rebuild and recovery are not same thing. If you need to recover data I'd go with R-Studio or UFS Explorer to recover the data rather than attempt in-place rebuilds/repairs.

Comment: No. Do not attempt to delete or recreate the RAID array. This destroys the metadata on the drives and resyncs the disks - all data lost. I don’t know why it’s not reading the RAID array correctly now, but from what I’ve read there isn’t anything you’ve done that would corrupt the drives. You should not be looking to repair the array or anything. Keep checking your settings and doing more research, there is no reason the drives wouldn’t be recognized properly after getting the settings back correctly. If you’ve done anything to write to those disks all bets are off.

Comment: From the image it looks like to me the system may be confused on the SATA ports or something. It’s weird but something changed in your BIOS settings. Did you add or remove any other hardware or swap any cables? Perhaps some ports were enabled or disabled with the reset.